# msmtp alternative that understands /etc/aliases

Tags: smtp, email

I'm looking for a simple smtp daemon, that supports aliases (due to issues with daemons, that refuse to send emails to anyone else than root).

If you don't know msmtp, then basically, I just want to configure an external SMTP that will handle all mail delivery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

msmtp seems to understand aliases, see http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/doc/msmtp.html#aliases . It seems just a matter of correct configuration.

Comment: Cool, didn't know that. Testing right now.

Comment: I switched to postfix in the end, because aliases are only supported in new versions, that aren't yet in debian stable.